# hive shell is not starting in cloudera

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera-cdh

I tried restarting my system, checked whether there is enough space or not and also made sure my hive server2 is running. But I'm getting these errors when given '$hive' in Cloudera.

```
Logging initialized using configuration in 
file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
WARN: The method class 
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

Comment: Check whether the hive metastore service is running or not.

Answer (score 0):

The process of starting Hive2 is changed, as Hive got deprecated. Usage of Beeline is recommended.

Beeline was developed specifically to interact with the new server. Unlike Hive CLI, which is an Apache Thrift-based client, Beeline is a JDBC client based on the SQLLine CLI — although the JDBC driver used communicates with HiveServer2 using HiveServer2’s Thrift APIs.

As Hive development has shifted from the original Hive server (HiveServer1) to the new server (HiveServer2), users and developers accordingly need to switch to the new client tool. However, there’s more to this process than simply switching the executable name from “hive” to “beeline”.

[More information provided over here](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/02/migrating-from-hive-cli-to-beeline-a-primer/)

Use the below command to enter into interactive mode. Beeline supports same commands that Hive server does. You can execute same script in Beeline without any modifications.

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://
```

To start the Hive metastore,

```
sudo service hive-metastore start
```

Comment: Beeline won't work if the metastore process  isn't started

Comment: As Cloudera distribution is being used, Hive metastore will start up at booting. However, I have added command to start Hive metastore to any answer.